# How to play ogg files on python

Tags: python

I looked everywhere, I don't find a way to properly play Ogg files, they all play wav!

My question is: Does somebody knows how to play Ogg files in python?

If somebody knows how I'll be very thankful :)

(I am on windows)

Comment: Have you tried https://pypi.org/project/PyOgg/?

Comment: I installed PyOgg using pip and the install worked BUT when I tried to import it for some reason it didn't see it

Comment: And even when I do manage to use PyOgg, it says PyOgg is not able to play files

Answer (score 1):

*use pygame* you can know about pygame here:[know about pygame](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pygame)
here is an example:

```
import pygame #pip install pygame
pygame.mixer.music.init()# initializing the module
pygame.mixer.music.load('your_ogg_file.ogg')# loading the ogg file
pygame.mixer.music.play()# this will simply play the loaded file.
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably to start a media player application to play the file using `subprocess.Popen`.

If you already have a media player associated with Ogg files installed, using the `start` command should work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Pyglet with ffmpeg:

https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/programming_guide/media.html

Answer (score 0):

i dont know if this will be useful for you case, but this is what i'm doing to play ogg file in python

```
from audioplayer import AudioPlayer
import os
from pydub import AudioSegment


audio_location="location of .ogg file that you want to play"     # location of the ogg file that you want to play
audio = AudioSegment.from_file(audio_location, format="ogg")
audio.export("outaudio.mp3", format="mp3")                       #converts the ogg tile to a temporary mp3 file for playing 
AudioPlayer("outaudio.mp3").play(block=True)                     # plays the converted file 
os.remove("outaudio.mp3")                                        # deletets the converted file leaving only the original .ogg file
```